# Can't open an specific Excel file - App crash

Tags: microsoft-excel, crash, macros

I encounter a problem with one specific .xlsm file.
On two different computers running Office 2016 and Windows 10, I get an Excel crash when opening it (during Excel loading). No error with other .xlsm files.

On some other computers with either Office 2013/2016 or Windows 7/10, I have no problem with the same file.

On non-working computers, I tried the following :

- Repair Office.
- Open the file while running Excel in safe mode.
- Disabling macros.
- Trying to recover the file from the Recover pane.
- Rename the file.
- Copy the file on the desktop before opening it.
- Check for the latest Office updates.

Windows Event Viewer reports "ntdll.dll" as the faulting module.

On a working computer, I tried to open the file and save it again. The new saved file does not work either.

Do you have some idea on what could cause the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel macro enabled files containing form controls are subject to the problem you describe. The cause of it is the October 4 update of Office 365.

Revert to version 16.0.7341.2035 using this guide: 
[How to revert to an earlier version of Office 2013 or Office 2016 Click-to-Run](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770432)

Turn off automatic updates until a fixed version is available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I ended up copying all informations in a brand new Excel file, which fixed the problem...  Nevertheless, I'll keep your solution in mind.